# Why does Spring doc say browsers only support GET and POST method

Tags: java, spring, http-headers

I was reading the documentation for `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/HiddenHttpMethodFilter.html)
and this comes up:

> Filter that converts posted method parameters into HTTP methods,
>   retrievable via HttpServletRequest.getMethod(). Since browsers
>   currently only support GET and POST, a common technique - used by the
>   Prototype library, for instance - is to use a normal POST with an
>   additional hidden form field (_method) to pass the "real" HTTP method
>   along. This filter reads that parameter and changes the
>   HttpServletRequestWrapper.getMethod() return value accordingly. Only
>   "PUT", "DELETE" and "PATCH" HTTP methods are allowed.

obviously browsers support more than just `GET` and `POST`, the link is not for an old version of spring dealing with archaic browsers, and I would imagine a widely-used framework like spring has an accurate documentation.

so what am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is mean by the reference is that `<form></form>` html element can only have method `POST` or `GET`:

This is for POST: `<form method="POST" ...></form>`

This is for GET: `<form method="GET" ...></form>`

Use it like code snippet bellow if you want to use other than POST and GET.
For example if you want to use PUT:

```
<form method="POST" ...>
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
</form>
```

If you use it like this `<form method="PUT" ...></form>`, it will not work.

Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-method) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you reference a piece of configuration in your `web.xml`, something like this:

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>method-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>method-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

What you reference is a feature that covers scenarios for browsers that don't support certain request types and it can still be useful in specific scenarios, if/when new request types are added, yet the browsers don't support them.

Another similar thing about "redundancy" that you might notice in many projects is i.e. utilization of `CharacterEncodingFilter` by many back-end developers when they set up when they build their REST api. Something like this would be common setup to see in such case in their `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

At that same time, many front-end developers set their own headers that basically do the same thing. This isn't wrong on their part at all, it is actually there to cover all possible scenarios and although some might find it redundant, others will find it detail-oriented.

**TL;DR:** **Spring is an enterprise-ready framework that provides not only new features but also covers the concerns such as edge-case scenarios, backwards compatibility and migration strategies towards new technologies.**

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to add only one filter, hope it will be helpful to you.

```
@WebFilter(asyncSupported = true, urlPatterns = {"/*"})
public class DeckCORSFilter implements Filter {

    /**
     * Logger
     */
    private static final Logger M_LOG = Logger.getLogger(DeckCORSFilter.class);

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see javax.servlet.Filter#destroy()
     */
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see javax.servlet.Filter#doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,
     * javax.servlet.ServletResponse, javax.servlet.FilterChain)
     */
    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest req, final ServletResponse res,
            final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (M_LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            M_LOG.debug("CORS filter enabled...........");
            M_LOG.debug("CORS filter req.........." + req.toString());

        }

        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");// allow access
        // from all
        // orgins
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");// allows only specified
        // methods
        // gives the value in seconds for how long the response to the preflight
        // request can be cached for without sending another preflight request.
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        // Content-Type, confirming that these are permitted headers to be used
        // with the actual request
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "x-requested-with,Content-Type,Authorization");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see javax.servlet.Filter#init(javax.servlet.FilterConfig)
     */
    @Override
    public void init(final FilterConfig filerConfig) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```